# Why the Uptime command gives me an error? ';' expected Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to put a command that tells you the uptime like "0d 2h 37m 27s" but I get an error.

This is the status.js code:

````
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class statusCommand extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'status',
      group: 'other',
      memberName: 'status',
      guildOnly: true,
      description: 'Show the status of the bot!'
    });
  }

  let totalSeconds = (client.uptime / 1000);
  let days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 86400);
  totalSeconds %= 86400;
  let hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
  totalSeconds %= 3600;
  let minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
  let seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds % 60);

      async run(message, args) { 
    const statusEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#6c6c6c')
      .setTitle('About Musik')
      .setDescription('Made by TheRedyYT')
      .addField('• Test', '```Test```', true)
      .addField('• Test', '```Test```', true)
      .addField('• Uptime', `\`\`\`${days} days, ${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes and ${seconds} seconds\`\`\``, true)
      .addField('• Test', '```Test```', true)
      .addField('• Category Count', `\`\`\`${message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == "category").size}\`\`\``, true)
      .addField('• Text Channel Count', `\`\`\`${message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == "text").size}\`\`\``, true)
      .addField('• Voice Channel Count', `\`\`\`${message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == "voice").size}\`\`\``, true)
      .addField('• Server Count', `\`\`\`${this.client.guilds.cache.size}\`\`\``, true)
    message.channel.send(statusEmbed);
}}
````

And this the error in the console:

```
/home/container/commands/other/status.js:15
  let totalSeconds = (client.uptime / 1000);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at /home/container/node_modules/require-all/index.js:56:46
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at requireAll (/home/container/node_modules/require-all/index.js:34:9)
```

This is a image of the error in Visual Studio Code
[image: Error with Uptime command Visual Studio Code Discord.js]

"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." ._.